# Adding multiple users to an Organic Group with a custom Rule Action

Tags: rules, organic-groups

I need a rule action that adds two specified users to an organic group.

I have written custom rule actions before so I created one that calls a function, `myModule_add_users_to_group()`, to do as I wish using official OG functions.

If I test this function it creates the two memberships correctly.

When I call this function as a rule action, `myModule_rules_action_info()`. Then it does NOT create these memberships correctly. Only the 2nd user membership will exist. I have debugged this and found the 1st user's membership is created but the removed. If I modify the function to just create one user it works (for either user). It seems adding the second user removes the first. Again, this only happens when this function is called as a rule action and is not what `og_group()` typically does.

Here is an example.

```
/**
 * Implement hook_rules_action_info().
 */
function myModule_rules_action_info() {
  return array(
    'myModule_add_users_to_group' => array(
      'label' => t('Add both loaded users to the new group'),
      'group' => t('Organic Groups'),
      'parameter' => array(
        'user1' => array(
          'type' => 'integer',
          'label' => t('New Member 1'),
          'description' => t('The 1st user to add to group.'),
          'optional' => false,
        ),
        'user2' => array(
          'type' => 'integer',
          'label' => t('New Member 2'),
          'description' => t('The 2nd user to add to group.'),
          'optional' => false,
        ),
        'node' => array(
          'type' => 'integer',
          'label' => t('Organization'),
          'description' => t('The group you wish to add the user too.'),
          'optional' => false,
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}


/*
* How I think it should be done
*/

function myModule_add_users_to_group($uid2,$uid2,$gid){
  //Relevant vars
  $values1 = array(
    'entity_type' => 'user',
    'entity' => $uid1,
    'field_name' => 'og_user_node',
  );
  $result1 = og_group('node',$gid,$values1);

  $values2 = array(
    'entity_type' => 'user',
    'entity' => $uid2,
    'field_name' => 'og_user_node',
  );
  $result2 = og_group('node',$gid,$values2);

}
```

I reviewed the code for the function `og_group()`. It does some data integrity and current state checks and then uses `og_membership_create()`. I decided to use `og_membership_create()` directly. If it worked I  would do my own integrity checking. It had the same issues

Example:

```
function myModule_add_users_to_group($uid2,$uid2,$gid){  
  // Get membership if exists.
  $og_membership1 = og_get_membership('node',$gid,'user',$uid1);
  if(!$og_membership1){
    $result1 = og_membership_create('node',$gid,'user',$uid1,'og_user_node');
  }

  $og_membership2 = og_get_membership('node',$gid,'user',$uid2);
  if(!$og_membership2){
    $result2 = og_membership_create('node',$gid,'user',$uid2,'og_user_node');
  }
}
```

I reviewed the function `og_membership_create()`. It creates these memberships by creating a new entity. So I tried. That. Same issues.

```
function myModule_add_users_to_group($uid2,$uid2,$gid){
  $values1 = array();
  $values2 = array();
  global $language;
  $field_name = 'og_user_node';
  $values1 += array(
    'group_type' => 'node', 
    'gid' => $gid, 
    'entity_type' => 'user', 
    'etid' => $uid1, 
    'state' => OG_STATE_ACTIVE, 
    'created' => time(), 
    'field_name' => 'og_user_node', 
    'language' => $language->language,
  );
  $values2 += array(
    'group_type' => 'node', 
    'gid' => $gid, 
    'entity_type' => 'user', 
    'etid' => $uid2, 
    'state' => OG_STATE_ACTIVE, 
    'created' => time(), 
    'field_name' => 'og_user_node', 
    'language' => $language->language,
  );

  if (!og_is_group_audience_field($field_name)) {
    throw new OgException(format_string('%field-name is not a valid group-audience field.', array('%field-name' => $field_name)));
  }

  // Get the type from the field.
  $field = field_info_field($field_name);
  $values['type'] = $field['settings']['handler_settings']['membership_type'];

  $wrapper1 = entity_property_values_create_entity('og_membership', $values1);
  $wrapper2 = entity_property_values_create_entity('og_membership', $values1);
}
```

Any advice?

Comment: I have more information. It may make this question worth removing.

Comment: The $gid in my rule is a group that was created earlier in the rule. I even 'save entity' on that group before my custom action.  My custom action is the very last action in this rule. However, I think this group entity is still "loaded" somehow in the rule and is 'resaved' at the end. Its audience field is probably not updated with my new memberships. Still very confusing and not working but this is what I am focusing on.

Comment: Pardon my ignorance but why is all of this necessary? Where do the two users and group come from?